# what specification for jsTree node icons?

Tags: css, jstree

I want to create my own node icons for jsTree application. A jsTree sample could be found [here](http://www.jstree.com/demo)

I want to know what specification the new icon has to have

- size
- transparent?
- could you recommend any program (mac or pc)
- anything else I forgot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bit of a weird question, but anyway:

The icons are individually `16x16`.

All the icons are inside one `.png` using alpha transparency (the background).

The [CSS Sprites](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/27/the-mystery-of-css-sprites-techniques-tools-and-tutorials/) technique is being utilized:
http://static.jstree.com/v.1.0pre/themes/default/d.png

[image]

Which image editor to use?

I'd use Photoshop, but any image editor that can handle `.png`'s alpha transparency will work.

Try: https://superuser.com/questions/25451/looking-for-a-good-free-image-editor

Comment: so the specs are like: 16x16 + alpha transparency + png

Comment: Per icon, yes. You should make sure you understand how CSS Sprites work, and keep them inside one image like they are now to enjoy the loading time reduction when it comes to loading one large image vs many smaller ones.

Comment: Responding to notification: In 2017, it's basically the same except it's 32x32: https://static.jstree.com/3.3.3/assets/dist/themes/default/32px.png